# Grails Spring Security only responds with ajax/JSON on login fail

Tags: ajax, spring, grails, authentication, spring-security

I'm using spring security in a grails app and when a login fails it always redirects to "login/authfail?ajax=true" and a json is rendered.

I even tried to redefine the 'ajaxAuthFailUrl' to be the same as 'defaultFailureUrl', but even though it redirects to '/login/authfail?login_error=1' I still getting the same json.

I dig the spring plugin to see why it 'thinks' it's an ajax request. Then on 'SpringSecurityService.java' I put some debug messages on 'isAjax' method. The result was, first of all, it calls 'isAjax' 2 times in a row. And the request is considered an ajax for different reasons:
there is a header 'ajaxHeader'
there is an ajax parameter on the request
and finally when it checks the SavedRequest's headers, it also finds it to be an ajax call.

I confess I'm lost, I don't have a clue about how to try to fix it...

I'm using:
Grails 2.3.8
spring-security-core:2.0-RC4
runtime ':spring-security-acl:2.0-RC1'
and I have a custom authentication handler that is set on BootStrap:

```
authenticationProcessingFilter.authenticationSuccessHandler = new MyUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler()
```

Comment: If you remove your custom auth handler, does it work as expected?

Comment: No, I haven't been able to make it work at all... Is there any way I could prevent ajax login? It might force grails/spring to render the proper error page...